# Epson workforce WF 3640 on/off switch stuck in off position

Tags: printer

How do you unstick the on/off switch on the printerbutton so you can turn the printer on? My button is stuck "depressed"  and will not pop back up.

Comment: Open the printer and clean the button/check for broken parts...?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a physical problem.

You can attempt to open up the printer and check for any obstructions, but printers are very delicate machines. I personally have broken two inkjet printers. If you feel overwhelmed by trying to physically fix the printer by yourself, contact Epson for a replacement.